# How to initiate using generic type in java

Tags: java, generics

my code is :

```
class ReferenceRangeBuilder<T extends DvOrderedBuilder> {

private DvTextBuilder meaningBuilder;
private DvIntervalBuilder<T> rangeBuilder;
   public ReferenceRangeBuilder() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

}
```

}

i want to initiate rangeBuilder, so that i can set value into it.
i want to do it inside the constructor.
for DvIntervalBuilder rangeBuilder i done it like:

```
 public DvIntervalBuilder() throws NoSuchFieldException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        // You may need this split or not, use logging to check
        String parameterClassName = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0].toString().split("\\s")[1];

        T lower = (T) Class.forName(parameterClassName).newInstance();
        T upper = (T) Class.forName(parameterClassName).newInstance();

    }
```

Comment: You've over-written the OP's changes there Lion.

Comment: @Zutty - It has just been rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem myself by writing a constructor like this, thanks to all for valueable time and opinions.

my solution is:

```
public ReferenceRangeBuilder(Class<T> claz) {
    try {
        lowerReferenceRange = claz.newInstance();
        upperReferenceRange = claz.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReferenceRangeBuilder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReferenceRangeBuilder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can create in instance of `T` inside the constructor? This information isn't available at runtime because of the way generics are implemented in Java. Read up on 'type erasure' for more information. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 0):

For this approach to work, your builder has to be sub-classed otherwise the type is unknown at runtime.

```
public class Main {
    static class Builder<T> {
        private final Class clazz;

        protected Builder() {
            Type type = ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            if (type instanceof Class)
                clazz = (Class) type;
            else
                throw new AssertionError("Builder needs to be sub-classed as " + type + " is unknown");
        }

        public Class<T> getClazz() {
            return clazz;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // works fine as sub-class records that the type is BigDecimal.
        Builder<BigDecimal> bigDecimalBuilder = new Builder<BigDecimal>() {
        };
        System.out.println(bigDecimalBuilder.getClazz());
        // doesn't work.
        Builder<BigDecimal> bigDecimalBuilder2 = new Builder<BigDecimal>();
    }
}
```

prints

```
class java.math.BigDecimal

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at Main$Builder.<init>(Main.java:21)
    at Main.main(Main.java:37)
```